# Kotlin - Como esperar clique do usuário pra retornar uma função chamada dentro do loop while

Tags: android, algoritmo, kotlin, sincronização

Tenho um algoritmo que via console ajuda o usuário na ordenação de uma lista de itens, ele funciona bem pra console (código abaixo), mas estou o adaptando a interface pra virar um app (conforme print)

Queria que assim que o usuário clicasse num dos dois botões, a função promptInput retornasse o texto correspondente ao botão, pra que o segundo while da função insertionSort funcionasse bem substituindo o readLine do console.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
override fun onCreateView() {
    val arr = arrayOf("finish homework", "finish chores", "go shopping")
    val result = insertionSort("What needs to be done first", arr)
    println(result.toList())
}

fun promptInput(comparison: String, str1: String, str2: String): String {
    println("$comparison: $str1 or $str2?");
    return readLine()!!
}

fun insertionSort(comparison: String, arr: Array<String>): Array<String> {
    println("arr size: ${arr.size}")
    var len = arr.size
    var i = -1
    var j: Int
    var tmp: String

    while (len-- != 0) {
        tmp = arr[++i];
        j = i
        while (j-- != 0 && (promptInput(comparison, arr[j], tmp) == arr[j])) {
            arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
        }
        arr[j + 1] = tmp
    }

    return arr.apply { reverse() }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Precisei utilizar LiveData e Coroutine do kotlin pra gerenciar a assincronicidade, alterei as funções pra funções suspensas com a utilização do lifecycleScope pra propriamente gerenciar as chamadas da função e o LiveData pra usar a programação reativa no Kotlin e permitir receber o valor imediatamente atualizado após o clique do usuário em um dos dois botões (par1 ou par2)

```
var par1:Button? = null
var par2:Button? = null
var parTextLive: MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData<String>()

var arr = arrayOf("finish homework", "finish chores", "go shopping")

override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false)
        par1 = root!!.findViewById(R.id.par1) as Button
        par2 = root!!.findViewById(R.id.par2) as Button

        lifecycleScope.launch {
            arr = insertionSort(arr)
            value!!.text=arr.toList().toString()
            par1!!.text="finished"
            par2!!.text="finished"
        }
        par1!!.setOnClickListener {
            lifecycleScope.launch {
                parTextLive.value = (par1!!.text.toString()) //valor da LiveData é atualizado
            }
        }
        par2!!.setOnClickListener {
            lifecycleScope.launch {
                parTextLive.value = (par2!!.text.toString()) //valor da LiveData é atualizado
            }
        }

        return root
    }

    suspend fun promptInput(str1: String, str2: String): String {
        return withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
            println("opções setadas: $str1 or $str2")
            par1!!.text = str1
            par2!!.text = str2

            val parText = (parTextLive.asFlow().first()) //aguarda até que a variável parTextLive receba um valor

            parTextLive = MutableLiveData<String>()  //zera o valor recebido pra poder aguardar novamente no próximo while

            return@withContext parText  //retorna o valor armzenado recebido
        }
    }

    suspend fun insertionSort(arr: Array<String>): Array<String> {
        return withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
            var len = arr.size
            var i = -1
            var j: Int
            var tmp: String

            while(len-- != 0) {
                tmp = arr[++i];
                j = i
                println("if-while")
                println(len)

                while (j-- != 0 && (promptInput(arr[j], tmp) == arr[j])) {
                    println("sec while")
                    println(arr[j])
                    println(tmp)
                    arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
                }
                arr[j + 1] = tmp
            }
            return@withContext arr.apply { reverse() }
        }
    }
```